# Python module name conflict

Tags: python, module, conflict

I have come across two Python modules that have to be imported using the same module name, e.g.

```
import foo
```

I know that the one I want provides certain functions (e.g. `foo.bar()`), so is there a way to cycle through the modules with the same name until I find the one that provides those functions? Or is there no way around other than renaming the module before installing?

Edit: just to clarify what I mean, both modules are inside site-packages:

```
site-packages$ ls python_montage-0.9.3-py2.6.egg
EGG-INFO montage
site-packages$ ls montage-0.3.2-py2.6.egg/
EGG-INFO montage
```

Comment: Is their anything that don't let you rename your module name ? because as far as i know it's the easy to solve this can of problems :)

Comment: Where are these modules found, path-wise? Do you have one in your site-packages directory and another in the current directory (of the importing file)? In that case you might be able to use absolute import to solve the ambiguity problem.

Comment: Both modules are inside one of the site-packages directory - I have edited the question to make this clearer

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way :

```
import imp
import sys


def find_module(name, predicate=None):
    """Find a module with the name if this module have the predicate true.

    Arguments:
       - name: module name as a string.
       - predicate: a function that accept one argument as the name of a module and return
             True or False.
    Return:
       - The module imported
    Raise:
       - ImportError if the module wasn't found.

    """

    search_paths = sys.path[:]

    if not predicate:
        return __import__(name)

    while 1:
        fp, pathname, desc = imp.find_module(name, search_paths)
        module = imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, desc)

        if predicate(module):
            return module
        else: 
            search_paths = search_paths[1:]
```

I bet there is some corners that i didn't take in consideration but hopefully this can give you some idea.

N.B: I think the best idea will be to just rename your module if possible.

N.B 2: As i see in your edited answer, sadly this solution will not work because the two modules exist in the same directory (site-packages/).

Comment: +1 for `__import__`, didn't know you could do a non-statement import and it's what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to hack around the two modules with the same name limitation, but unless you are doing this simply for educational purposes, I wouldn't recommend it. The end result will be confusing and unmaintainable. I highly recommend renaming one or both of the modules instead of messing around with obscure Python import related features.

Answer (score 0):

Since python 2.5 ([and PEP 328](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328)) absolute import is the prefered way of managing modules in python.
In your case, your module tree is certainly like this :

```
/src/first_level/foo
                /other_foo
    /second_level/foo # with the bar method
```

If you want to use the foo module with the bar method, use this :

```
import second_level.foo
```

Comment: I don't think I can do this because it is the top-level module name that is the same - I've edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy that you can figure out the filenames through some other heuristic, then you should be able to use imp.load_module to load them separately.

See http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.load_module

In your case, although both eggs are on the python path, I believe eggs do some magic whereby each egg acts as a path. You might be able to set the egg file as the path argument to `imp.find_module` in order to load them separately.