# Package name conflict between `emoji` and `django-emoji`

Tags: python, pip

I need to use the `django-emoji` and the `emoji` library in a single Django project. Both installed via pip. Both of these libraries get imported from a package named `emoji`:

When importing from `django-emoji`:

```
from emoji import Emoji
```

When importing from `emoji`:

```
from emoji.core import get_emoji_regexp
```

Any idea how to rename the package a library installs to and yet still have it installed via `pip`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937739/python-module-name-conflict. Unfortunately no real answer over there.

Comment: Saw the lack of answer there after I asked this question. Does this mean that there is no answer? That would be a sad hole in the python tooling.

Comment: Well which Python version are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.12.

Comment: So far I see that there is no way to do this. The theory is that packages on PyPI should be installed into unique top-level directories. This is violated in some cases. The solution is either to modify one of the conflicting packages or add an option to `pip` to support an override.

Answer (score -1):

```
import emoji as django_emoji
django_emoji.Emoji
```

Wouldn't that work, or am I missing something?

Comment: That does not work because I installed the `emoji` package after `django-emoji`. Now when I try to import from `emoji`, it only sees the `emoji` package. `django-emoji` is effectively invisible. I don't ave an issue with what the package ends up being called after I import it into my code. The issue is that the python import mechanism cannot access both of these packages, as both are known as `emoji`.